# My php/mysql isn't working like it did this morning. Beginner/Intermediate help

Tags: php, mysql

I made some alterations to my code, and now it won't function properly. My **img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/1.png** and **img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/2.png** aren't showing up (both are highlighted in the code below).

My pagination's link '**prev**' and '**next**' also aren't showing up. Both are also highlighted.

Anyways, here's basically my mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `thumbnailID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `link` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `alt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`thumbnailID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ;
```

And here's my php code:

```
<?php
  $objConnect = mysql_connect("sadadsaf","w3f","scdsf") 
                or die(mysql_error());
  $objDB = mysql_select_db("sdfv");
  $pic2 = "SELECT * FROM images";

  if (!isset($_GET['Page']))
    $_GET['Page']='0';

  $pic1 = mysql_query($pic2);
  $Num_Rows = mysql_num_rows($pic1);
  $Per_Page = 16;   // Per Page
  $Page = $_GET["Page"];

  if(!$_GET["Page"]) {
    $Page=1;
  }

  $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
  $Next_Page = $Page+1;
  $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);

  if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page) {
    $Num_Pages =1;
  } else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0) {
    $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
  } else {
    $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
    $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
  }

  $pic2 .=" order  by thumbnailID ASC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
  $pic1  = mysql_query($pic2);
  $cell = 0;
  $link1 = "SELECT * FROM images";
  $link = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($link1));**
  $alt1 = "SELECT * FROM images";
  $alt = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($alt1));
  $time1 = "SELECT * FROM images";
  $time = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($time1));
  echo '
    <div id="tablediv">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="17" cellspacing="0" class="table">
        <tr>';

  while($pic = mysql_fetch_array($pic1)) {

    if($cell % 4 == 0) {
      echo '</tr><tr>';
    }

    if($cell == 2) {
      echo '
        <td>
          <div class="customimage">
            <a href="/misc/deadend.php">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/1.png" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>'; // This line includes one of the <img> tags having issues
    } elseif ($cell == 3) {
      echo '
        <td>
          <div class="customimage">
            <a href="/misc/deadend.php">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnail/2.png" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>'; // This line includes one of the <img> tags having issues
    } else {
      echo '
        <td>
          <a href="/' . $link["link"] . '.php">
            <div class="image">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imagetitle/' . $pic["pic"] . '" 
                   alt="' . $alt["alt"] . '" 
                   height="190" 
                   width="190" 
              />
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="submitted">submitted&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="timeago">
            <abbr class="timeago" title="' . $time["time"] .'"></abbr>
          </div>
        </td>'; 
    }
    $cell++;
  }
  echo '</tr></table></div>';
?>

<br />
view more:

<?php
  if($Prev_Page) {
    echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page'>**prev**</a> |";
  }

  if($Page!=$Num_Pages) {
    echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page'>**next**</a> ";
  }
?>

<?php
  mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Nevermind, they're not highlighted. They should have asterisks around them though.

Comment: I think you might have a flaw in your design logic there. $link1, $alt1 and $time1... and you never move through the (same) array held in each of them. Therefore $alt["alt"] should fail, as should $time["time"]...

Comment: @Tomalak (+1) You're right, but maybe some tips for user657847 would be helpful?

Comment: @Tomalak: how can the formatting be so bad when there is _no formatting_? Anyway, I think that's a minor concern compared to the bad choice of symbol names :P

Comment: @Tomalak: I cleaned it a bit. Better?

Comment: Trust me. I know my formatting is horrible. Really, I don't even know what the standard formatting is, and never bothered to look it up (if there were standard semantics like there is for html)

Comment: @Chris: I'm sure they would be. Feel free to give them if you have the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter the line so you can get more information about what's happening:

```
$link1 = "SELECT * FROM images";
$result_link1 = mysql_query($link1);

if(!$result_link1) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die();
}

// just for testing
echo mysql_num_rows($result_link1) . '<br/>';
$link = mysql_fetch_array($result_link1);
```

This will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: What is echoed out by the mysql_num_rows function? Are you positive it doesn't die in the `if` statement I included above?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I just found out my problem was that my host was undergoing maintenance for some hours now, effectively keeping my page stagnant unaffected by my changes. The link shows up now. Do you have any idea regarding my two other problems? Regarding the images not showing up and the prev and next not showing up?

Comment: The prev page isn't showing because you $Prev_Page is 0 ($page -1), and `if(0)` will not enter the TRUE block of an IF statement

Comment: Yes, I meant for the prev to show up on the paginated 2nd+ page. The next isn't showing up on my first page however, as it should.

Comment: `echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page'>**next**</a> ";` Should be  echo `" <a href ='{$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]}?Page=$Next_Page'>**next**</a> ";` Can you also echo out $Num_Pages somehwere to confirm the value is as it should be.

Comment: ahhhh, your answer, made me realize the problem. Fixed it. (the problem is not addressed in the code above) Sorry for the trouble, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This won't really answer your question, but it will let you in on some of the conventions that make your code more readable and thus your questions about bugs easier to answer.  Things in your code:

- Try to put related lines in order, this allows the reader to know all of what is going on with one action of your script.  For example, in your first few lines you open the DB, assign your query to a variable, then in the middle you check for your GET variable which could easily have been after you actually perform your query, and then you perform the query. Checking for the GET had no bearing on your query, better to bunch the query stuff together.
- You assign a variable Page depending on what's in the GET['page'] variable, and then you go back to using the GET variable for your conditional directly after.  If you're using $Page for ease of use, use it.
- Bracketed code should have either the beginning and ending bracket on its own line indented once to the start or some (including myself) put the beginning bracket one space after the start line and then the ending bracket indented once from the start on its own line.  This makes it easy to read, especially when you get into very long conditional blocks and nested conditionals.
- Variables should be descriptive as to what they are.  You did this with most of them such as Next_Page and the like, but pic1, pic2, alt, link1, link2, etc are confusing and seem to all be different sql query strings - none of the variable names really mean anything regarding what they are.
- It's not really a big deal, but starting variable names with a capital letter is considered to be "improper" for lack of a better term.  Camel Case is the convention I see used the most (first word started with lowercase, subsequent words started with upper, for example: nextPage or numPages).  Another convention I see often is one that you use a few times and not on others, it is using all lowercase and separating words with an underscore.  Generally a coder will save capitals for class names.  In your code, feel free to use whatever you'd like, but stick to it, it helps when trying to remember how you formatted the name of a variable 5 pages away.

All of this sort of thing helps read your code better and helps you to organize it.  Standardization also helps other coders understand what you are meaning to code.  I thought I'd write this so you had an idea of what some of the comments above were speaking to.  See the following link for a tutorial on many of the common conventions:

http://www.blackgate.net/consulting/php_coding_guidelines.html

Have fun!